# HTML/Bootstrap - spacing and positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

thanks for trying to help me out.

I made this, I like how it looks but I am having a very hard time to bring it in position.

http://jsfiddle.net/93zb8Lzs/1/

The main thing I want is that the 6 elements

```
<li><a href="#">home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">über uns</a></li>
<li><a href="#">anfahrt</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">produkte</a></li>
<li><a href="#">leistungen</a></li>
<li><a href="#">termin</a></li>
```

on the bottom, but I do not know how to bring them down.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the specific code in your post or in a jsfiddle. And also add you images. Your question should be easy to read for everybody.

Comment: The complete code + pictures is in the last link. I had to change the links because I was not allowed to post more than 1 link at the time.

Comment: Yeah, we can read this. But we don't want to download your code, we just want to help to debug it. So please create a fiddle, or post it here with the code snippet tool.

Comment: The violet bar is a picture at size of 368 x 138, please resize your image.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I changed the question now so it is hopefully easier to understand and more accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/93zb8Lzs/6/

```
<img src="https://www.google.at/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="368" height="138" alt="Logo" />
<!-- Nvigationselemente -->   
    <div class="nav">
    </div>

img {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, that solution is just exactly what I tried to do, and it's so simple, too!

Answer (score 0):

remove class pull-left and pull-right from ul elements and add in CSS

```
ul {
    display:inline;
}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/93zb8Lzs/5/) you have fiddle

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I think you misunderstood my question, see indubitablee's answer for the solution.